# Инициализация статического поля методом, который может выкинуть исключение

Tags: java

Как присвоить статическому полю `clients` результат статического метода `makeMassClient`?

```
class GPR extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ListSelectionListener {
static Client[] clients=BankingSystem.Parser.makeMassClient("D://clients.out");
```

Проблема в том, что справа от равно появляется синтаксическая ошибка "Unhandled exception type IOException".

> Multiple markers at this line
>   Unhandled exception type IOException
>   Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: Поместите эту конструкцию внутрь try-catch блока, который ловит IOException

Comment: @iksuy а разве можно в полях класса делать tre-catch?
Ведь появляется новая синт.ошибка: Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

Comment: Собственно, то что вам продемонстрировали в ответе я и имел ввиду - try-catch внутри статического блока инициализации.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте, например, статический блок инициализации:

```
static Client[] clients = null;
static {
  try {
    clients = BankingSystem.Parser.makeMassClient("D://clients.out");
  } catch(IOException e) {
    // Обработка исключения...
  }
}
```

Comment: А можно присвоение напрямую сделать? Т.к. это поле мне нужно использовать в другом классе, а оно вначале инициализировано как null. В итоге я не могу получить возвращенные данные с метода

Comment: Выполнение статических блоков инициализации выполняется при инициализации класса в порядке их объявления. Не совсем понял в чем ваша проблема

Comment: @Parshi  была еще одна маленькая ошибка в коде. Исправил, всё работает! Спасибо!